# JIRA: create filter with a common story

Tags: jira

I want to create a filter to select all unassigned issues which are a subtask of story "Some Story".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to know the ID of "Some story", let's call it SS-10.  You can then use an issue filter like this:

```
parent = SS-10 AND assignee IS EMPTY
```

If you need any further filtering, you can just add "AND" clauses on the end, like this:

```
parent = SS-10 AND assignee IS EMPTY AND issuetype = Sub-task
```

Comment: Yeay! Worked. Thanks. Did not know the parent field, could not find it in the documentation.